# Iterate over all documents in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, nlp

I have a solr instance with 200M+ documents. I would like to find an efficient way to iterate over all those documents.

I tried using the start parameter to formulate a list of queries:

```
http://ip:port/solr/docs/select?q=*:*&start=0&rows=1000000&fl=content&wt=python

http://ip:port/solr/docs/select?q=*:*&start=1000000&rows=1000000&fl=content&wt=python

...
```

But it is very slow when start gets too high.

I also tried using the cursorMark parameter with an initial query like this one:

```
http://ip:port/solr/docs/select?q=*:*&cursorMark=*&sort=id+asc&start=0&rows=1000000&fl=content&wt=python
```

which I believe try to sort all the documents first and crash the server. Sadly I don't think it is possible to bypass the sort. What would be the proper way to do it?

Comment: Have you *tried* removing the sort parameter?

Comment: The sort parameter seems mandatory, I have a bad request error if I try to remove it.

Comment: Okay, perhaps you could try sorting by _docid_ (that is: `sort=_docid_+asc,+id+asc`). You might also experiment with fetching smaller pages (less rows)

Comment: id in my case is my docid. Is _docid_ supposed to be a default solr document attribute? I couldn't find it in the field list. I tried querying only 10 rows, but it still crashes.

Comment: `_docid_` is not really a field, per se, it's the lucene's internal identifier, used to fetch documents.

Comment: For some reason my query is rejected when using _docid_, I'm debugging this right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I couldn't make it work with the cursor, even though it's probably me not knowing well enough how to use the tool. If you are having the same problem as me here are 3 tracks:

- Track one: use cursor sorting using `_docid_` as suggested by @femtoRgon. I couldn't make it work but I didn't have a lot of time to allocate to it.
- Track two: use export handled as suggested by @Persimmonium
- Track three (lazy track): what I did in the end is I keep using incremental `start` values, but I switch from `wt=python` to `wt=csv`, which is much faster and allows me to query by batches of 10M documents. This limits the amount of queries and the cost of using `start` instead of  `cursorMark` is kind of amortized

Good luck, post your solutions if you find anything better.

Answer (score 2):

this is a very well known antipattern. You just need to use [cursorMark feature](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results) to go deep into a result set.

if  cursorMark is not doable then try the [export handler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Exporting+Result+Sets)

---

Comment: This is the second thing I tried, sadly I believe Solr is trying to sort all the 200M+ documents and the server is crashing. Is it possible to bypass the sort ?

Comment: aded another option